# Naming conventions for instances and methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, coding-style

What is the standard way to name an instance:

```
NSString* myString;
```

or

```
NSString* my_string;
```

Similarly, what is the standard way to name a method:

```
(void) getMyName;
```

or

```
(void) get_my_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`camelCase` is the standard. Have a look at Apple's [Cocoa coding guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also getter methods do NOT have the `get`keyword in it. So `getMyName` should just be `myName`.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php) may helps you to understand and how it should be written, Though i also suggest the link provided by jtbandes.The [cocoa guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH) has the pretty good definition along with nice examples for quick look.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the guidelines (1) applied in your product (2) suggested by the language.

Many guidelines for C++, Java and other languages suggest **camelCase**, like `getMyName()`, while
**python** suggest **lower_case_with_underscores**, like `get_my_name()`, see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) .

Comment: What you say is perfect truth, but is unhelpful (or, if you prefer, irrelevant) given that this question was tagged as objective-c.

Comment: @Jirka. Yes, you are right! I'm sorry not to notice that tag. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I am also your downvoter (sorry for not mentioning that before, I'm also quite new here).  However, I also believe that you are putting forward an important truth, just perhaps unaware that some languages (Objective C, Python, C#...) have a pretty consistent culture of a single industry standard coding style, unlike C++ with its traditional variety of conventions.  If you decide to do more research and edit your answer to better express your viewpoint after that (and also better reflect the question), I will be more than happy to adjust my vote and to delete my obsolete comments.